# Error shown on creating a new maven project.

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

```
D:\Eclipse workspace>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.nrifintech -DartifactId=DBAIEI -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
Jan 23, 2014 2:47:53 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jan 23, 2014 2:47:53 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Jan 23, 2014 2:48:14 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jan 23, 2014 2:48:28 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Jan 23, 2014 2:48:49 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jan 23, 2014 2:48:49 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
Jan 23, 2014 2:49:34 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Jan 23, 2014 2:49:34 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

When i try try to create a maven project using this command then this error is shown.
And this continues on.Dont know why this is happening .My maven is installed correctly.
My maven is installed in C: drive.

Comment: You seemed to have problems with your internet connection: `INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset`. First check you internet connection. Are you behind a proxy? If yes you need to configure that in the settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The important part here is `Connection reset`. This means: In the middle of talking to the server, the connection was suddenly lost.

This either means there is a firewall between you and the server or that the server has a problem (-> check the server's error log).

You can also try to open http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom in your browser (POMs are simple XML files). That might give you a better error message or an idea where to look (if the browser can open the file, you probably needs to configure Maven to use the same proxy settings as the browser).